# Column in CSV to list in python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I've seen a lot of posts about doing this backwards, but I haven't been able to find any way to write the contents of a column in a csv file to a list.  After I have this I'll loop through to add all of the unique value to a separate list and count the number of total unique values.
This is what I have:

```
b=[]
c=[]
servers = []
fname=(r'file')
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    severities = Counter(row[3] for row in reader)
    servers = list(row[9] for row in reader)
    for row in reader:
        print (row[9])
        for servername in servers:
            if servername not in b:
                b.append(servername)
```

I'm open to better ways to do this.  Any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output exactly? You cannot loop over `reader` twice, at least not without rewinding `f` to the start with `f.seek(0)`. Not that that would be the efficient way of doing it.

Comment: So you want to have a `Counter()` of the 4th column (`row[3]`) and a *unique* list of the 10th column (`row[9]`)? You are not using `c` here, is that needed at all?

Comment: ^that's exactly what I want.  The counter works fine, I want b to contain the unique values of column 10 at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the `reader` three times:

```
severities = Counter(row[3] for row in reader)  # First time
servers = list(row[9] for row in reader)  # Second time
for row in reader:  # Third time
```

When you iterate the first time, you 'exhaust' it, so it won't yield any item the second and third time.

You should do something like this:

```
severities = Counter()
servers = []
for row in reader:
    severities[row[3]] += 1
    servers.append(row[9])
    print row[9]
```

This is enough to make the code work.

Here are some other tips. They aren't required to fix your code, however you'll surely benefit from them:

- I think you want to place the `for servername in servers` loop out of the `for row in reader` loop.
- If you use a `set` or an `OrderedSet` instead of a list for `b`, you can completely avoid 
  the `for servername in servers` loop and replace it with a single line:

  ```
  b.update(servers)
  ```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks a ton I've been looking at this for far too long.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to loop over `reader` just *once* and collect the counts and unique names for the servers in your loop:

```
severities = Counter()
servers = set()

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        severities[row[3]] += 1
        servers.add(row[9])
```

This assumes you don't care about the order `servers` are listed in in the CSV file.

If order *does* need to be preserved, use a separate `seen` set:

```
severities = Counter()
servers = []

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    seen = set()
    for row in reader:
        severities[row[3]] += 1
        if row[9] not in seen:
            servers.append(row[9])
            seen.add(row[9])
```

If the file is relatively small, you could also get away with transposing the columns; that's overkill here, but would look like:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    cols = zip(*reader)  # transpose the rows to columns
    severities = Counter(cols[3])
    servers = set(cols[9])
```